# Circuitikz: make only the line thicker towards the component, not the component itself

Tags: circuitikz

I'd like to make the line towards Rprobe thicker, but not the resistor itself

```
\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
    
    \begin{circuitikz}
\draw (0,0) to[V,v=\qty{10}{\volt}, invert] (0,6)--(2,6) to[R,name=A] (2,3) to[R,name=B] (2,0)--(0,0);
\node[above,rotate=90] at (A.south) {\qty{100}{\kilo\ohm}};
\node[above,rotate=90] at (B.south) {\qty{100}{\kilo\ohm}};
\draw (4,3) to[R,name=C] (4,0)--(2,0);
\node[above,rotate=90] at (C.south) {$R_{\text{probe}}$};
\node[below,rotate=90] at (C.north) {\qty{1}{\mega\ohm}};
\draw [-Latex, line width=1.5pt] (4,3) -- (2,3);
\draw[-Latex, line width=1.5pt] (4,0) -- (2,0);
%\node[circ] at (4,3) {}; % Default label (you can customize it)
\node[above right] at (4,3) {$V_{\text{osc}}$};
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although I would advise against using separate nodes for labels, I will post the minimum modification here.

You are using a line thickness of 1.5pt, which is 3.75 times bigger than the default 0.4pt used by the rest of the diagram. So you have to scale the line thickness of the resistor down to 1/3.75=0.2666:

```latex
\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (0,0) to[V,v=\qty{10}{\volt}, invert] (0,6)--(2,6) to[R,name=A] (2,3) to[R,name=B] (2,0)--(0,0);
\node[above,rotate=90] at (A.south) {\qty{100}{\kilo\ohm}};
\node[above,rotate=90] at (B.south) {\qty{100}{\kilo\ohm}};
% 0.2666 = 1/(1.5/0.4)
\draw[line width=1.5pt] (4,3) to[R,name=C,resistors/thickness=0.2666] (4,0)--(2,0);
\node[above,rotate=90] at (C.south) {$R_{\text{probe}}$};
\node[below,rotate=90] at (C.north) {\qty{1}{\mega\ohm}};
\draw [-Latex, line width=1.5pt] (4,3) -- (2,3);
\draw[-Latex, line width=1.5pt] (4,0) -- (2,0);
%\node[circ] at (4,3) {}; % Default label (you can customize it)
\node[above right] at (4,3) {$V_{\text{osc}}$};
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

[image]

BTW I think it looks quite horrible, but well... as another detail, you can see that the lower arrow looks "bad" (this is due to a `--(2,0)` in the probe resistor path) and a wonky connection of the thick line at the right corners. To correct that:

```latex
\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (0,0) to[V,v=\qty{10}{\volt}, invert] (0,6)--(2,6) to[R,name=A] (2,3) to[R,name=B] (2,0)--(0,0);
\node[above,rotate=90] at (A.south) {\qty{100}{\kilo\ohm}};
\node[above,rotate=90] at (B.south) {\qty{100}{\kilo\ohm}};
% 0.2666 = 1/(1.5/0.4)
\draw[line width=1.5pt] (4,3) to[R,name=C,resistors/thickness=0.2666] (4,0);
\node[above,rotate=90] at (C.south) {$R_{\text{probe}}$};
\node[below,rotate=90] at (C.north) {\qty{1}{\mega\ohm}};
\draw [-Latex, line width=1.5pt] (4,3) to[short, .-] (2,3);
\draw[-Latex, line width=1.5pt] (4,0) to[short, .-] (2,0);
%\node[circ] at (4,3) {}; % Default label (you can customize it)
\node[above right] at (4,3) {$V_{\text{osc}}$};
\end{circuitikz}
```

[image]

Details in the manual, section 6.4, "Lines joins between path components".

Answer (score 3):

You could do this:

```
\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
    
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (0,0) to[V,v=\qty{10}{\volt}, invert] (0,6)--(2,6) to[R,name=A] (2,3) to[R,name=B] (2,0)--(0,0);
\node[above,rotate=90] at (A.south) {\qty{100}{\kilo\ohm}};
\node[above,rotate=90] at (B.south) {\qty{100}{\kilo\ohm}};
\draw [Latex-,line width=1.5pt] (2,3) -- (4,3);
\draw [-Latex,line width=1.5pt] (4,3) to [R,name=C,line width=0.4pt] (4,0) -- (2,0);
\node[above,rotate=90] at (C.south) {$R_{\text{probe}}$};
\node[below,rotate=90] at (C.north) {\qty{1}{\mega\ohm}};
%\node[circ] at (4,3) {}; % Default label (you can customize it)
\node[above right] at (4,3) {$V_{\text{osc}}$};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, nice, simpler than mine. +1.